# Finding the equivalent Unicode codepoint given an extended ASCII codepoint and a codepage in Java?

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

I am trying to write a method to find the equivalent codepoint in Unicode of the same visual character in ASCII given a specific codepage

For example, given a character say `char c = 128`, which is '€' in Windows-1252 codepage, running the method

```
int result = asUnicode(c, "windows-1252")
```

should gives `8364` or for the same `char c = 128`, which is 'Ђ' in Windows-1251 codepage, running the method

```
int result = asUnicode(c, "windows-1251")
```

should gives `1026`

How this can be done in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` shouldn't really be a `char`, but a `byte[]` of bytes in the corresponding encoding, eg. windows-1252.

For this simple case, we can just wrap the `char` into a `byte[]` ourselves.

You need to decode those bytes to Java's `char` type which represents BMP code points. Then you return the corresponding one.

```
public static int asUnicode(char c, String charset) throws Exception {
    CharBuffer result = Charset.forName(charset).decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] { (byte) c }));
    int unicode;
    char first = result.get();
    if (Character.isSurrogate(first)) {
        unicode = Character.toCodePoint(first, result.get());
    } else {
        unicode = first;
    }
    return unicode;
}
```

The following

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    char c = 128;
    System.out.println(asUnicode(c, "windows-1252"));
    System.out.println(asUnicode(c, "windows-1251"));
}
```

prints

```
8364
1026
```

Comment: Thank you, thats pretty fast answer! Not sure why it has to be in byte[] but it works.

Comment: @user1589188 Looks like both windows-1251 and windows-1252 are single byte encodings. If it needed more than 2 bytes to represent its characters, you'd need more than a `char`. Also, the Charset API consumes bytes (during decoding).